# ScheduledFuture returns null when a task is submitted or scheduleAtFixedRate

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool, future, futuretask

I am trying to schedule a job to run every 10 minutes using ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor. There are 10 threads in the thread pool.
Code looks like:

```
ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor executor = new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(10, r -> {
                    Thread t = new Thread(r);
                    t.setName("thread");
                    return t;
                }, (runnable, pool) -> {
                });

List<ScheduledFuture<?>> listOfFutures = new ArrayList<>();

ScheduledFuture<?> future = executor.scheduleAtFixedRate(() -> {
    try {
        System.out.println("John is a good guy");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // eat the exception
    }
}, 0, 10, TimeUnit.MINUTES);

listOfFutures.add(future);
```

Now, if 100 tasks were scheduled and their future were added to a list.
When we try to iterate the list and do future.cancel(), out of 100, 2-3 futures turn out to be null.

What is the possible reason here?

I had to add an initial delay of 2 seconds in order to ensure that the future is not null. But I also have an ExecutorService with the same problem (future is null in few cases). But there is no delay that can be added there.

Comment: Try to not silently swallow all exceptions, as the truth may be hidden there.

Answer (score 2):

Most likely it is that the executor pool has been shutdown or encounted some issue. You've not implemented the `RejectedExecutionHandler` very clearly, it just discards errors so you have no idea when they occur.

You can get more information on when / how any executor service issue occurs if you drop the last parameter to `new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor` to remove the pointless handler `(runnable, pool) -> {}`. This will instead use the default abort policy.

Alternatively change your rejected handler so that it tells you of the problem when there is one:

```
(runnable, pool) -> { 
    throw new RejectedExecutionException("*** FAILED ***"
               +" isShutdown()="+pool.isShutdown()
               +" getActiveCount()="+pool.getActiveCount()
               +" queue size="+pool.getQueue().size());
}
```

When running with your original handler `(runnable, pool) -> {}` you will need to check each call as you otherwise will have no indication of when there is an issue:

```
ScheduledFuture<?> future = executor.scheduleAtFixedRate(() -> { ... }, 0, 10, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
if (future == null)
   throw new RuntimeException("*** FAILED to add new action ***");
```

Comment: ok, so I have not written the RejectedExecutionHandler. But in my case, it gets executed smoothly if a delay is added. If some issue occurs or the executor has shut down, it should execute the task

Comment: @Sart Edit the question with details of your cases where `future` is returned as null and there isn't a call to `RejectedExecutionHandler`, or any code that re-produces the issue.